# How to make multi line header text while autogeneratecolumn set to true

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

In my stored procedure I have a column that haS a dynamic column name that’s multiline. In MS SQL this column looks exactly how I want it, but in my gridview it’s single line. I am using autogeneratecolumn=“true” because there are so many different types of column names that could be displayed. How can I have that column only be multiline?
Thanks in advance

update: here is my sproc and gridview
sproc

```
declare @min varchar(max), @max varchar(max), @c varchar(max), @slqStmt varchar(max)
select @min = max(somecolumn1), @max = max(somecolumn2) from someDB.dbo.someTable
where Name = @somenamesenttosproc
set @c =  @min + ' - ' +  @max +'
BOTTOMLINEOFCOLUMNTEXT'

set @slqStmt = '
SELECT Name ' + 'AS [' + @c +']' +'
from someDB.dbo.someTable '

PRINT @slqStmt
EXEC(@slqStmt)
```

gridview

```
<asp:GridView CssClass="border border-top-0 border-start-0 border-end-0 border-dark z-0 w-100" ID ="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" cellpadding="10" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" GridLines="Both" BorderColor="Black" EmptyDataText="No records found..." AllowPaging="true" PageSize="100" Font-Size="Small">
<%-- Grid Style --%>
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#c4143b" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" CssClass="border border-bottom-0 border-dark sticky-top-15"/>
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f7bac7" />
<RowStyle CssClass="border border-top-0 border-bottom-0 border-dark" />
<PagerSettings Position="Top" />
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="pagination-ys" />
```

Comment: You might want to share the relevant part of your code.

Comment: i updated my question to include relevant code @LajosArpad

Comment: Thank you! What is the value of `Name` that should be in multiple rows? Also, is this article helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e26523a-09fe-4694-8238-130c5e0d15a8/multiple-line-on-gridview-header?forum=aspwebformsdata ?

Comment: The name column is one of 5 columns in the table. It’s a unique name for a specific lot number.

Comment: No, that article is showing how to code in the header. I am using AutoGenerareColumns =“true” in order to set my column name to whatever  dynamic column name my Sproc creates. I believe if I add a header template It will create duplicate columns. Is there a way to pass a return key like \n inside the column name in my sproc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to wonder - REALLY wonder if this is a good idea?

I have to look at the sample stored procedure - even worse looking!

In other words, the crazy hand stands you going though here is OH SO MUCH worse then just setting up a header. Do you really not have control of what table and grid you going to design for a given page? Really?

You can imbed a "br" in the column text. But if the data for the heading is suppled by the data source, then markup is ignored. So, this issue makes this even worse!

However , you can cook up (assume) some char in the heading to be the start of the 2nd line.

SQL rather limited, you can use assume a "_" or maybe a "$" or a "#" in the supplied header. (but, few choices - sql don't like much else like a + or others (invalid syntax)

Lets do a simple example:

And lets thus assume a "_" (under score) will be 2nd line of heading.

So, this markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="40%" CssClass="table">


</asp:GridView>
```

And code to load is this:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            @"SELECT FirstName as First_Name,
            LastName as Last_Name,
            City,
            HotelName as Hotel_Name,
            Description FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();

        // optional, convert all "_" to 2nd line in heading
        for (int i = 0; i < rstData.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text =
                rstData.Columns[i].ColumnName.Replace("_", "<br/>");
        }
    }
```

And now we get this:

[image]

So, I would try to avoid hacking to death the source SQL. But, I suppose introduction of the assumption of some char in the column name, and them processing out as per above is workable.

As a general rule, I would try and keep that SQL clean, nice and simple, and not hack to death existing SQL. The requirement to NOT know the column name(s) ahead of time is red flag in this design - and I would spend greater efforts attempting to avoid that design assumption in the first place.

Comment: It worked thanks @Albert D. Kallal. I know its not conventional, but I am working on a web app and database that I didn't personally start. So, I'm trying to work around a lot of pre existing code. Plus, this dynamic header column was a very desired trait for this gridview per customer. For web app's I actually like to be sql heavy because if customers change anything it is easier to alter (in my opinion) than the app it self. Very nice solution.

Comment: Its not the end of the world. All I'm just saying is having a on the fly table for a given GV is not ideal. But, hey, GV's will auto generate columns. So, at the end of the day, the feature does exist - and you are 100% free to adopt and use such a feature. And, as the above shows, we can quite easy alias the columns in sql, and have a wee bit of extra code to break that column heading into two lines. You have a need - the need exists. So, just saying try to avoid such on the fly data grids - but it still a choice, and above shows it not all that bad anyway, right!